# Upgrade Spring boot 1.5.10 to 2.1.11

Tags: spring-boot

I am new to spring boot. I am trying to upgrade spring boot 1.5.10 to 2.1.11. Now I have this error and I do not know how to fix it

**Exception while restarting my application class.**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>             at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>             at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>             at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>             at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:66)
>           Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.supportsSourceType(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z

**Here is my POM.xml with added dependency.**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>com.academy</groupId>
        <artifactId>search</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <name>search</name>
        <description>fetch search results</description>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.11.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath/>
        </parent>
        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
            <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
            <sleuth.version>2.0.1.RELEASE</sleuth.version>
            <docker.image.prefix>academy</docker.image.prefix>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-properties-migrator</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                <version>2.24.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>1.16.16</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.academy</groupId>
                <artifactId>integration-framework</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
                    <version>${sleuth.version}</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.8.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-report</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-check</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>check</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <rules>
                                    <rule implementation="org.jacoco.maven.RuleConfiguration">
                                        <element>BUNDLE</element>
                                        <limits>
                                            <limit implementation="org.jacoco.report.check.Limit">
                                                <counter>COMPLEXITY</counter>
                                                <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                                <minimum>0.90</minimum>
                                            </limit>
                                        </limits>
                                    </rule>
                                </rules>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>

Please help me.
```

Comment: Run `mvn spring-boot:run` and post the console output.

Comment: @EugenCovaci [INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.11.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ search ---
[WARNING]
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
   at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:543)
 at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.supportsSourceType(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z
    at org.springframework.context.event.GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.supportsSourceType (GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.supportsEvent (AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:295)
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.retrieveApplicationListeners (AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:225)

Comment: BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  8.651 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-01-13T15:37:24+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.11.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project search: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.supportsSourceType(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z -> [Help 1]

Comment: What is your java version `java -version` and what is your `mvn dependency:tree` output? Most likely you have a mismatch in library versions.

Comment: Can you make your project public on Github?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your version of Spring Cloud is incompatible with your version of Spring proper (and Spring Boot). Latest version of Spring Cloud is 2.2.1.

And oh, while you're at it update to Spring Boot 2.2.2 as 2.1.x is going end of life soon.

Comment: Thanks for response. So I should upgrade to 2.2.1 directly?

Comment: @RohiniTurkar yes,  but be prepared for having to make changes to your code. I did an upgrade of a major system from Spring Boot 1.4 to 2.2 late last year. It went pretty smooth but there were some nasty surprises as well.

Comment: I changed to spring 2.2.0 release. now i m getting below error. Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Comment: cloud version :  <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring-cloud.version>